# Restore ENTIRE system ROOT / (CLARIFICATION)

Tags: filesystems, cp, disk, inode, borgbackup

I recently had to restore the disk with **borg**. So via live linux, I entered my disk file system, deleted everything (root **/**), and restored a backup of a specific date. *Now I ask myself:* **do you need to align the disk or the files?** (*inodes*, etc... in this case, some *inodes* have also changed). That is, I know that some files (mainly system files) cannot be copied normally with the classic "cp". In this case a "cp" command was not used but a copy was made anyway. Don't the files have to *"move them to the beginning of the disk"?* Is there a difference, in this case, between a **HDD** and an **SSD**? (my system is on ***SSD***)....and, can i copy the system with the classic **cp**? I would like more detailed explanations on this.

Thanks and apologize for my english.

Answer (score 3):

On modern Linux systems, there might be no files sensitive to absolute disk location at all, if your system boots in UEFI style.

Even if your system boots in legacy BIOS style, modern versions of GRUB will write their location-sensitive parts to the empty space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition whenever possible... and if you don't specially override the modern convention of starting the first partition at exactly 1 MiB from the beginning of the disk, there will be plenty of space for that. This area is not part of any partition and so not really accessible as files of any kind.

If the filesystem UUID has changed (ie. you had to run `mkfs` or change the partitioning) then you might have to re-install the bootloader. Typically the procedure to do that is to boot Linux from an external media, `chroot` into the  troubled system, mount `/boot` if it is a separate partition, mount `/boot/efi` if an UEFI system, and run the bootloader installation command, e. g. `grub-install /dev/sda`.

The kernel and initramfs file are, essentially, just regular files. If they have the right name in the right directory in the expected filesystem, the bootloader will find them.

Comment: So theoretically, I could use **cp** or **rsync**, right? And in case of **HDD** (only), after copying, I proceed with a defrag in order to move the files to the beginning of the disk, right?

Comment: Yes, you could use `cp` or `rsync` to backup/restore your root filesystem. And about that defrag... modern filesystems generally use various clever allocation strategies to keep the fragmentation under control. Some filesystem types might not even need manual defragmentation unless the pattern of usage is especially fragmentation-inducing. With SSD, random reads are essentially just as fast as sequential reads, so defragmentation is not needed at all.